# Fetch in set with order

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

My core data object look like this:

```
Person
-------
presonId
name
```

Now suppose i got an array of `personsIds`, and I want to fetch all the `Person` objects that includes is this `personsIds` array.

So my fetch request will be:

```
NSArray *personsIds = [self getPersonsIds];  

// fetch all persons with ids in personsIds
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Person"];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"presonId in %@", personsIds];  
NSArray *results = [self.context executeFetchRequest:request error:&anyError];
```

Now my issue is this:
**The order of the `personsIds` is important and I want that the `results` array will be ordered in the same order.**

I can't mess with the `personId` array, can't sort it or anything..

notice that the `personsIds` array may have more objects than the `results` array

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the fetch request result with `NSSortDescriptor`:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *sort2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"personId" ascending:YES];

request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@[sort1, sort2]];
```

How the sort descriptors should look like depends on how you want the result to be sorted. That depends on how your `personIds` array is sorted.

If you can't describe the sorting in such a general way you will need to loop through your results and sort them manually.

Comment: that problem is that my personId array isnt sorted, but its order is important so i cant sorted. I need the results to be the same order as my personId array as is. maybe i shouldn't use the word sort here.. ill update my question

Comment: Then you need to do the sorting yourself by looping over the results and sorting that like the personIds array is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

As Cornelius says, you use a sort descriptor. In your case the sorting is defined as "in the order of some other list". So we need a way to map personId into "index in the original list" and then sort on that. Let's build an `NSComparator` to help us (none of this is actually tested, but it should compile):

```
NSComparator comparatorForOriginalList(NSArray *list, NSString *key) {
  NSArray *order = [list valueForKey:key]; // The personIds in the order we want
  return ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
     // We're passed personIds, map them to their locations
    NSUInteger idx1 = [order indexOfObject:obj1];
    NSUInteger idx2 = [order indexOfObject:obj2];

    // And do the surprisingly tedious task of comparing them (why is this still so hard?)
    if (idx1 > idx2) {
      return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    if (idx1 < idx2) {
      return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
  };
}
```

Given a list and a key, this returns a function that compares the location of the first object's value for that key in the list to the second object's and tells you whether they were in order or not.

With that in place, creating the sort descriptor is easy:

```
NSString *key = @"personId";
NSComparator comparator = comparatorForOriginalList(originalList, key);
NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:key
                                           ascending:YES
                                          comparator:comparator];
```

Comment: This is nice, didn't think of that :)

Comment: I don't think I can use this kind of comparator with Core data, when I try to I get exception: "unsupported NSSortDescriptor (comparator blocks are not supported)"

Comment: I also tried to do in memory sort after the fetch but it takes a lot of time, around 3 minutes for ~4000 objects.

Comment: This kind of sort is O(n^2), so it will scale poorly (though 3 minutes for 4000 records does seem excessive, so you may have some optimization work you should be doing). To improve that, you can try creating a dictionary of personId->index so that you're later lookups are faster. Or put your results into a dictionary of personId->record to look them up on demand.

Comment: Certainly not using SQL. Core Data in some configurations is built on top of SQL, but it doesn't require it and you can't rely on it or access the underlying SQL store directly.